# How to make android test link avaliable?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

i want to make my android test link available for other people to download
but app is in review and link doesn't works

Does open testing app link need to be reviewed to be available ?
my link:

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.dillenhub.dillenfirstapp

expected link :

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/me.fstoke.GoblinCaravan

my open testing is not available and in review , Do i need to wait the review to make the web testing link available ?  [https://imgur.com/a/K1hA6xZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rBry.png)